# react query not updating value passed to state

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I really feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I'm just playing around/learning react query.. I have the below code:

```
import {useReducer} from 'react'
import AppContext from './context'
import reducer from './reducer'
import apiClient from './http-commom'
import {useQuery} from 'react-query'

function App() {
  const getClientList = useQuery(
    ['client-list'],
    async ({signal}) => {
      return await apiClient.post('/v1/clientlist', {signal})
    },
    {enabled: true, refetchOnWindowFocus: false}
  )

  let clientList = getClientList?.data?.data?.recordset

  const initalState = {
    clientList: clientList,
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initalState)

  console.log(clientList) // works ['client1','client2','client3']
  console.log(initalState.clientList) // works ['client1','client2','client3']
  console.log(state.clientList) // undefined

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
      <div>testing</div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Why is the state value showing as undefined but the other two work fine?

I was trying to pull the state.clientList into another component like so...but moved the console log into the App component so I could compare all

```
function MenuBar() {
  const {state,dispatch} = useContext(AppContext)
  const {clientList} = state
  console.log(state.clientList) // undefined...
...
```

Any help is much appreciated! Maybe I jut need to go for a walk until it comes to me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The initial state of useReducer is only evaluated on the first render cycle. But in the first render cycle, the `data` returned from `useQuery` is still `undefined`, because its async state - it needs to be fetched first.

When data comes in after some time, updates to `initialState` are not passed to the reducer, because that's how "initial" state works.

So, you can write a `useEffect` that dispatches an action that updates your state, but it's an anti pattern. The question is really: Why do you need to copy state from react-query somewhere else. react-query is a state manager, and it should be the single source of truth for your server state.